# Filtering Panda dataframe through various columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Panda dataframe called `finalDf`.

I would like to filter it, by keeping values in columns `'0'` to `'90'` that are greater than a boundary (let's say `'5'`).

I have done it (clumsily) like:

```
finalDf = finalDf[(abs(finalDf['0'])>Boundary )|(abs(finalDf['10'])>Boundary )|(abs(finalDf['20'])>Boundary )
```

etc.

But was wondering how to do it in a clearer way.
I created a list `deltas = [i for i in range(0,100,10)]` matching the column labels  of interest (but i believe the column indexes are strings, not doubles).

Any help appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are close to what you want.

```
cols_to_drop = [str(x) for x in range(low_boundary, upp_boundary)]

df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This will drop any columns in the range of "low_boundary" and "upp_boundary".